# Swift 4 Codable & generics

Tags: swift, generics, swift4, codable

I'm adding cache to my app with PINCache and I am in a situation where delegate methods to encode/decode are called by the cache system. 
Those methods are generic but the generic value do not conform explicitly to `Codable`. Because they are delegates, I can't change the signature to make the generic type conform to `Codable`.

```
func modelForKey<T : SimpleModel>(_ cacheKey: String?, context: Any?, completion: @escaping (T?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    guard let cacheKey = cacheKey, let data = cache.object(forKey: cacheKey) as? Data, T.self is Codable else {
        completion(nil, nil)
        return
    }

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let model: T = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        completion(model, nil)
    } catch {
        completion(nil, nil)
    }
}
```

With this code, I'm having the following error:

> In argument type `T.Type`, `T` does not conform to expected type `Decodable`

How can I force my `decoder` to accept the generic value?

Comment: Could you please add the code calling the function `modelForKey<T>` as well? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Codable can't be implemented in extensions (yet?) and since SimpleModel is internal to PINCache you can't make it conform to Codable.

If possible I would suggest switching to a caching library with a protocol that supports Codable like [Cache](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache)

Answer (score 4):

Try `func modelForKey<T : SimpleModel, Decodable> ...` to require that type is constrained to Decodable.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to check that it conforms to `Decodable`:

```
guard let cacheKey = ... as? Data, T.self is Decodable else {
```

Comment: What is the difference with my code ? I'm already checking the if `T.self` is `Decodable`.

Comment: @Morniak where are you checking that?

Comment: Last instruction of my guard (line 2)

Comment: @Morniak In the code you included you're checking for `Codable` not `Decodable`

Comment: Oh right ! But Codable imply Decodale. Anyway, I tried with Decodable and I got the same issue. Checking the type do not change the type of the variable in the scope. And the Codable system need real types so I can't cast my var to Codable.

Comment: @Morniak Can you add `Decodable` conformance to `SimpleModel`?

Comment: `SimpleModel` is a protocol provided by the library so I can't add a `Decodable` conformance

Answer (score 0):

IMO the problem is not with PINCache.

`T.self is Codable` doesn't tell the compiler more about the type `T`, so `decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)` won't pass the type checking, even if `T` is a `Decodable`.

I think forking RocketData will be the easiest solution here (if you want to keep using RocketData + `Decodable` and all your models conform to `Decodable`). Make `SimpleModel` conform to `Decodable`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to create `CustomProtocol: Codable, SimpleModel`
2. If point 1 doesn't work, try to create custom class `CustomClass: SimpleModel, Codable` and use `modelForKey<T : CustomClass>`